# submiting form in another website using post request using jquery but failing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, cross-domain

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sachindivakar/2xmvnkr7/2/)

I am trying to summarise a text by posting data on to a website which provide that feature 
i have used two approaches but both failed miserably

1. At first i tried to load it in an iframe and tried to access contents inside it but it shows some browser restriction error

> Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin "http://fiddle.jshell.net" from accessing a frame with origin "http://autosummarizer.com". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.

1. Then i tried to send a post request to the domain that to failed [here](http://autosummarizer.com/index.php)  is the website which i am trying to post data to but receive following error

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://autosummarizer.com/. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://fiddle.jshell.net' is therefore not allowed access.

### Jquery

```
var v='Banking Jobs, recruitment in Thiruvananthapuram, Kerala | Indeed ...Jobs 1 - 10 of 60 ... 60 Banking Jobs available in Thiruvananthapuram, Kerala on Indeed.com. ... Testhouse India Private Limited - Thiruvananthapuram, Kerala ... www.indeed.co.in';

alert($('iframe').contents().find("h2").html());

$.post( "http://autosummarizer.com",{ text: v,submit:"Summarize" },{dataType : "jsonp" } ,function( data ) {
  alert( data );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The website you're trying to add to your iframe element must enable [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).
That Auto Summarizer apparently has an API, I suggest you get in touch with them to get access to their API and use this service properly.